Дана строка из заглавных латинских букв и точек. Определите максимальное количество идущих подряд символов, среди которых не более четырёх точек
Подскажите как сделать это задание? Не понимаю почему код просто считает символы, подскажите пожалуйста что не правильно и как лучше сделать.
s = input("Введите строку: ")

left = 0
right = len(s)
dots_count = 0
symbol_count = 0
symbol2 = 0
symbol = []

while left != right:
    if s[left] == '.':
        dots_count += 1
    else:
        symbol_count += 1

    if dots_count == 4:
        dots_count = 0
        if s[left] == '.':
            dots_count += 1
        else:
            symbol2 += 1

    left += 1
    symbol.append(max(symbol_count, symbol2))
print(max(symbol))


Каким способом вы решаете задачу?

У вас right никогда не меняется. Почему бы не запустить его с нуля?

Ваша программа не двигает right, а этот индекс должен проходить с начала строки:
def max4p(s, nump):
    leng = len(s)
    left = 0
    right = -1
    cnt = 0
    maxlen = 0

    while (right < leng):
        while (right < leng) and (cnt <= nump):
            right += 1
            if right < leng:
                if s[right] == '.':
                    cnt += 1
        maxlen = max(maxlen, right - left)

        while (left < right) and (cnt > nump):
            if s[left] == '.':
                cnt -= 1
            left += 1

    return maxlen

print(max4p('..ab.cd.ef.g', 4))    #11
print(max4p('.....a.b.c.e.', 4))   #8


Почему то выводит просто колличество букв с 4 точками.

Как это? Привёл примеры использования

Ну он считает, но вот например в первом примере ответ должен быть 7, а во втором 4. Или вот например abc..de.fg...h тут будет ответ 7. То есть надо посчитать колличество символом между которыми в общем максимум 4 точки.

Понятно... Вы неправильно интерпретируете условие задачи. Ну или неточно его нам привели.

Условие задачи я скопировал и вставил)

Всё-таки неправильно понимаете. Не "между которыми". Точка - тоже символ.

Если я вас правильно понял то вот решения данной задачи:
import re

text = "d.a..d..da..e.w.ww..."
matches = re.findall(r'\.{1,}', text)
result = len(max(matches))

print(result)

- 3


Вы тут ищите максимальное количество подряд идущих точек. Это не то что спрашивается в задании.

Тут вы считаете максимальное количество идущих подряд точек, это немного не то что нужно.

Ваша программа что-то странное считает:



строка
что возвращает программа
верный ответ




.a.a.a.a.a.
5
9: .a.a.a.a.a.


.a.a.a.a..
4
8: .a.a.a.a..


.a.a.a..
3
7: .a.a.a...



Кажется вы возвращает число букв-не-точек, а надо возвращать длину подстроки с точками. И даже если это исправить, всё равно ваша программа проверяет не все возможные подстроки.
Решение
indices(seq, item) возвращает все индексы значения item в последовательности seq. Она ещё добавляет в начале -1 и в конце индекс за концом последовательности.
interval(seq, k) пускает по последовательности два итератора с интервалом k позиций.
main() вводит строку и перебирает все пары точек с интервалом в пять  позиций. Из них выбирается пара с максимальным расстоянием. Если такой пары нет, печатается длина строки.
def indices(seq, item):
    yield -1
    i = -1 # to process empty seq
    for i, v in enumerate(seq):
        if v == item:
            yield i
    yield i + 1


def interval(seq, k):
    it = iter(seq)
    ring = [v for _, v in zip(range(k), it)]
    i = 0
    for v in it:
        yield ring[i], v
        ring[i] = v
        i = (i + 1) % k


def main():
    s = input()
    print(max(
        (b - a - 1 for a, b in interval(indices(s, '.'), 5)),
        default=len(s)
    ))


main()


Хм, я когда читал вопрос даже не подумал, что это буквы, перемежающиеся точками. Я думал точка - это равноправный символ. Так конечно задание более понятное.

@CrazyElf, не обязательно перемежающиеся. Это могут быть предложения, отделённые точками. Такая задача уже была недавно. Но найти её не легко :). Вот и я шифруюсь, жду какой-нибудь реакции от ТС.

Можете пожалуйста подсказать как это сделать?

Попробовал ваш код, все равно выводит колличество всех букв

@NICE, покажите пример с ошибкой.

Вот это ввел ..ab.cd.ef.g и мне написало сумму всех букв и 4 точек

..ab.cd.ef.g -> 11. Вся строка - 12 символов, в ней пять точек. Без первой точки получится подстрока из одиннадцати символов, в которой четыре точки. Что не так? Какой по вашему мнению должен быть ответ?

Хорошо, возможно я не совсем так понял условие задачи. Я понял так что должно выводить без учета точек. Извиняюсь за наезды)
Спасибо!
